# Is there any way to work with flexible JSON in java? (Spring Boot API)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing

So I need to create an API with Spring Boot to manage different JSON. My problem is that these JSON can and will change in the future their structure, saying something like this:

Today's structure:

```
{
"name" : "example",
"surname" : "example"
}
```

Possible future structure:

```
{
"name" : "example",
"surname" : "example",
"data_array" : [
   {
       "path": "example"
    }
 ]
}
```

So, my question is, is there any way to manipulate this kind of JSONs (the "flexible" ones), I don't know if this is possible.

Thank you in advance

Edit.
I don't know if I'm explaining this well enough, right now, to work with those JSONs I need to parse them into an object that I've already created with those fields as parameters. I would like to know if there is a way to not limit those JSONs with a defined object in java.

Comment: Why not add versioning to your API?

Comment: So you are concerned about additions mainly? Those are normally backwards compatible changes, i.e. they don't break older clients…

Comment: If using Jackson (the default in Spring Boot) you could easily add the `data_array` to your class later on. If you don't want to add classes at all you could use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Comment: above answers pretty much sum up the solution, either use versioning or just keep on adding to the response class, in case of json, they just wont have any value or maybe use can use json deserializer to not include any null values

Comment: General rule of thumb, when you need to handle dynamic fields/properties without developer intervention, then you will put the dynamic fields in a Map<String,?>.